# How can I catch a MouseEvent via Spring AOP advice

Tags: java, spring, aop

How can I catch a MouseEvent via Spring AOP?

For example, how can I call an advice when `label` below is pressed?

```
label.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent event) -> {
    // Do something
});
```

I know that to call an advise on all `getters()`:

```
@After("execution(* get*(..))")
public void popStage() {
    System.out.println("Advice called");
}
```

but what of events?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the label action you want to intercept is from a JavaFX or Swing class and not from a Spring Bean/Component. Spring AOP is a proxy-based "AOP lite" approach only working with Spring Beans/Components. In order to apply AOP to non-Spring objects you need to use full [AspectJ](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/) which is possible [within Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj) or stand-alone.

If you need more information, I do too. Provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to demonstrate your problem and I will see what I can do.